# move_uploaded_file not working on remote server but working on local server

Tags: php, html, upload

Please I do not really know what I am doing wrong here. I have a page for image upload. It's working perfectly on localhost but as soon as I uploaded it to remote server, It's not working as I want it. I have changed the folder permission, I have changed the directly still not working. It's not giving me any error. it's showing file uploaded successfully but anytime I check the folder, It's empty. Please help me out. This my code below.

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])) 
{ 
  $tmp_name = $_FILES['passport']['tmp_name']; 
  if (empty($tmp_name) == false){
      $name = $_FILES['passport']['name']; 
      $type = $_FILES['passport']['type']; 
      $size = $_FILES['passport']['size']; 
      list($width, $height, $typeb, $attr) = getimagesize($tmp_name); 

     if($width<=160 || $height<=160) 
     { 
        if($type=='image/jpeg' || $type=='image/jpg' || $type=='image/png')
        {
            if($size<='20000') 
            { 
                if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                { 
                    $name = addslashes($name); 

                    $extract = fopen($tmp_name, 'r'); 
                    $content = fread($extract, $size); 
                    $content = addslashes($content); 
                    fclose($extract);  
                    //Place image in the folder
                    $newname="$studentID.jpg";
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['passport']['tmp_name'],"../passports/$newname");
                    $msg = "<center><p style ='color: #4F8A10; background-color: #DFF2BF; border-radius:.5em; width: 350px; border: 1px solid #D8D8D8; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; padding-left: 12px'>Passport uploaded successfully.. Click the link below to continue</p></center>";
                } else {
                    $uploaderror = "<p style='color: #D8000C; background-color: #FFBABA; border-radius:.5em; width: 300px; border: 1px solid #D8D8D8; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase'>Error has occured... Please try again</p>"; 
                }
            } else {
                $uploaderror = "<p style='color: #D8000C; background-color: #FFBABA; border-radius:.5em; width: 300px; border: 1px solid #D8D8D8; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase'>$name is more than 20kb</p>"; 
            }
        } else {
            $uploaderror = "<p style='color: #D8000C; background-color: #FFBABA; border-radius:.5em; width: 300px; border: 1px solid #D8D8D8; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase'>$type is not in acceptable format</p>"; 
        } 
    } else {
        $uploaderror = "<p style='color: #D8000C; background-color: #FFBABA; border-radius:.5em; width: 300px; border: 1px solid #D8D8D8; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase'>$name should be 160px * 160px</p>"; 
    }
} else {
    $uploaderror = "<p style='color: #D8000C; background-color: #FFBABA; border-radius:.5em; width: 300px; border: 1px solid #D8D8D8; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase'>Please choose a file to upload</p>"; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Any error? if not then please use absolute destination path also check for directory permissions.

Comment: No error. Could you please help me with the absolute destination path and directory permissions?

Comment: look for [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

Comment: are you using windows server or linux?

Comment: windows for local server and linux for the remote server

Comment: use `getcwd()` in the directory first to get absolute path where you want to move save uploaded files.

Comment: What have you changed the folder permissions to? The `apache` user will need access to the entire path, and write permissions to the folder in question. Also, placing the command ` ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top of the file *may* lead to PHP giving you an informative message.

Comment: Thanks Ben Hillier... I have added the error display command to my code. So it's showing this error Warning: move_uploaded_file(passports/2016002.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/buth_net/nursingSchool/passport.php on line 60

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpHtz0en' to 'passports/2016002.jpg' in /var/www/html/buth_net/nursingSchool/passport.php on line 60